# What are the three boxes? ロ, 口 and 囗

Tags: kanji, orthography

I was scrolling the [Kanji Unicodes](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) and spotted three box-like characters.

I'm well aware that `ロ` is the katakana `ro`, as for which the other two are, I'm not sure.

Among the three `ロ` (katakana), `口` (kanji), `囗` (kanji), what is which Kanji, and how do they differ in writing?

[image]

(*For people without support for these characters, here is a an image of how these characters look like*)

Comment: `as for which of the other the moon is`  Did you mean "mouth"?  "Moon" is 月 and could not possibly be confused for any of these.

Comment: @istrasci changed the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same order you wrote: ロ is the katakana `ro`, as you said. The second one is the kanji for mouth (口) and the last one is the 31th kangxi radical also known as [enclosure radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_31). There are 214 radicals and most of them are very important to understand how kanjis work. If you search in the link you provided through CTRL + F, when you insert the mouth kanji, you're going to see the next kanjis are related to mouth, like 古, which means "old" and it's made of 十 (ten) and 口 (mouth). Ten means "a lot" in this case, like "many people" and "mouth" means the message transmitted over the years[¹](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%8F%A4). If you do the same thing with the enclosure radical (囗) you might find some examples of things enclosed, like 囚 (prisoner), which is self-explanatory: [a person enclosed](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%9B%9A). I provided two links above for the kanji etymology but I also used a kanji etymology book but it's written in another language, so it's not useful to mention it here. Just for your information, there are many kanjis that changed a lot over the years, so sometimes you'll see an element inside a kanji, like the mouth kanji, but it has nothing to do with mouth, like [西](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E8%A5%BF) (west).

As for the stroke order, I think they're all the same. That's why depending on the font of your computer/browser, they will look the same.

*Probably because of some technical reasons that I don't know, the links of the kanjis are not working in the YellowBridge dictionary. You should manually input those characters in the **[Word](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php)** tab in the **Chinese to English input field**, and after that, the **Etymology** tab will be available.*